# "When I last saw him he was dying, but now you'd hardly know he'd been ill"

Tags: semantics, progressive-aspect, pragmatics, aspect

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, page 122, reads

> *He was dying* is an *implicature* because of the possibility of cancellation, as in *When I last saw him he was dying, but now you
>   would hardly know he had been ill*; other speakers might insist on *he
>   seemed to be dying* or the like, and for them subsequent reaching of
>   the terminal point has the strength of an **entailment**

Why does the verb *seem* changes the implicature of *die* into an entailment?

Comment: That is interesting, because the Cambridge English Dictionary does not recognise the word ‘implicature’ at all.  As far as I know, this word was coined by the American linguistic philosopher Searle.  It’s meaning is well explained in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/implicature/.   The verb ‘die’ is an awkward one, to be sure.  We are all ‘dying’ from the moment of birth.  It is often a hyperbolic idiom (dying of hunger/boredom.  But to say “I am dying” literally, I claim to be obout to die quite soon.  If I don’t, I was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You've got it backward: CGEL is saying that for some speakers bare *he was dying* entails his subsequent death, because dying is a process which ends in death. These speakers insist on something like *he seemed to be dying*—which evokes a contrast between the "seeming" and the reality—to change the entailment into an implicature.

Here's the relevant excerpt:

[image]
[image]

*The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002, p. 122).

Comment: I'd done a snip to write a post, and then saw you'd written one. So I though I'd give you a snip as a present. Of course, if you don't like it, please take it out!

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks! I guessed there was probably more to Huff&Puff's argument than was quoted, but was too lazy to look it up.